# Why the NuGet doesn't copy some dlls as in packages.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget, nuget-package

I have a problem where I want to copy Google.Authenticator.dll nuget from C:\ProjectX\packages into C:\ProjectX\project.Web\Bin.
Here what I done so far:

- cleared the nuget cache
- update the nuget     nuget update -self
  But it not working.

The package I have is Google.Authenticator , in the packages.config I have

But it doesn't pick that dll and copy it across.

Comment: Have you tried

"Manage Nuget Package" >> "Google Authenticator"

Comment: Yes, google auth is installed under  project\packages but when I tried to delete it doesnt restore while I build the project

Comment: Could you provide a list of the packages you've configured and then check they're referenced to the correct project?